# Attach user id from access token using DTO

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I create POST endpoint to create a new entity.
I also created schema for mongoose with field userId (to connect this entity to specified user) and DTO which I use on my POST method.

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Post("/")
createAction(@Request() req, @Body() createActionDto: CreateActionDto) {
    return this.actionService.createAction(req?.user?.userId, createActionDto);
}
```

DTO:

```
import { IsString, IsNumber, IsUrl } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateActionDto {
    userId: string;

    @IsString()
    name: string;

    @IsNumber()
    timeStart: number;
}
```

Schema:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema()
export class Action extends Document {
    @Prop()
    userId: string;

    @Prop()
    name: string;

    @Prop()
    timeStart: number;
}

export const ActionSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Action)
```

In the req property I have userId. What is the best way to create an entity and attach userId extracted from token?

Should I pass req to the service, and in the service set userId property on DTO like this?:

```
@Injectable()
export class ActionService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(Action.name) private actionModel: Model<Action>,
    ) { }

    async createAction(req: string, createActionDto: CreateActionDto) {
        createActionDto.userId = req.user.userId

        // ... save to mongoose createActionDto
    }
}
```

Is it a correct solution or there is another, a better way to deal with it?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would set the `userId` in the controller in order to not having to pass it around:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Post("/")
createAction(@Request() req, @Body() createActionDto: CreateActionDto) {
    createActionDto.userId = req?.user?.userId;
    return this.actionService.createAction(createActionDto);
}
```

If you have many different controllers and DTOs that require the `userId` you could also define an Interceptor and do it there in order to reduce duplication:

```
@Injectable()
export class SetUserIdInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  public intercept(_context: ExecutionContext, $next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {    
   const request: any = _context.switchToHttp().getRequest(); //instead of any you could also define a super-class for all DTOs that require the `userId`-property    
   request.body?.userId = req?.user?.userId;
   return $next;
  }
}
```

You can then use this interceptor on your route as follows:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Post("/")
@UseInterceptors(SetUserIdInterceptor)
createAction(@Body() createActionDto: CreateActionDto) {
    return this.actionService.createAction(createActionDto)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also have a question about DTO's that does not reflect schema, e.g. schema has an initial array offers: [], but at the initial moment I would not to fill this array using data from the API. So, should I set those fields in the controller (default values)?

Comment: Not quite sure about that one, but you could let mongoose do it: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html
Not sure NestJS supports this though.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried, but what about a scenario when the user will send me that data in a request? Mongoose default will be overridden.

Comment: That's true - setting it through the controller would be ok, I guess. But maybe this is input for another question and someone else knows a better way :)